# Stream audio from mic to IBM Watson SpeechToText Web service using Java SDK

Tags: java, speech-to-text, ibm-watson

Trying to send a continuous audio stream from microphone directly to IBM Watson SpeechToText Web service using the Java SDK. One of the examples provided with the distribution (`RecognizeUsingWebSocketsExample`) shows how to stream a file in .WAV format to the service. However, .WAV files require that their length be specified ahead of time, so the naive approach of just appending to the file one buffer at a time is not feasible.

It appears that `SpeechToText.recognizeUsingWebSocket` can take a stream, but feeding it an instance of `AudioInputStream` does not seem to do it appears like the connection is established but no transcripts are returned even though `RecognizeOptions.interimResults(true)`.

```
public class RecognizeUsingWebSocketsExample {
private static CountDownLatch lock = new CountDownLatch(1);

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, InterruptedException {
SpeechToText service = new SpeechToText();
service.setUsernameAndPassword("<username>", "<password>");

AudioInputStream audio = null;

try {
    final AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(16000, 16, 1, true, false);
    DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);
    TargetDataLine line;
    line = (TargetDataLine)AudioSystem.getLine(info);
    line.open(format);
    line.start();
    audio = new AudioInputStream(line);
    } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

RecognizeOptions options = new RecognizeOptions.Builder()
    .continuous(true)
    .interimResults(true)
    .contentType(HttpMediaType.AUDIO_WAV)
    .build();

service.recognizeUsingWebSocket(audio, options, new BaseRecognizeCallback() {
  @Override
  public void onTranscription(SpeechResults speechResults) {
    System.out.println(speechResults);
    if (speechResults.isFinal())
      lock.countDown();
  }
});

lock.await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
}
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

-rg

Here's an update based on German's comment below (thanks for that).

I was able to use [javaFlacEncode](https://sourceforge.net/projects/javaflacencoder/files/) to covert the WAV stream arriving from the mic into a FLAC stream and save it into a temporary file. Unlike a WAV audio file, whose size is fixed at creation, the FLAC file can be appended to easily.

```
    WAV_audioInputStream = new AudioInputStream(line);
    FileInputStream FLAC_audioInputStream = new FileInputStream(tempFile);

    StreamConfiguration streamConfiguration = new StreamConfiguration();
    streamConfiguration.setSampleRate(16000);
    streamConfiguration.setBitsPerSample(8);
    streamConfiguration.setChannelCount(1);

    flacEncoder = new FLACEncoder();
    flacOutputStream = new FLACFileOutputStream(tempFile);  // write to temp disk file

    flacEncoder.setStreamConfiguration(streamConfiguration);
    flacEncoder.setOutputStream(flacOutputStream);

    flacEncoder.openFLACStream();

    ...
    // convert data
    int frameLength = 16000;
    int[] intBuffer = new int[frameLength];
    byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[frameLength];

    while (true) {
        int count = WAV_audioInputStream.read(byteBuffer, 0, frameLength);
        for (int j1=0;j1<count;j1++)
            intBuffer[j1] = byteBuffer[j1];

        flacEncoder.addSamples(intBuffer, count);
        flacEncoder.encodeSamples(count, false);  // 'false' means non-final frame
    }

    flacEncoder.encodeSamples(flacEncoder.samplesAvailableToEncode(), true);  // final frame
    WAV_audioInputStream.close();
    flacOutputStream.close();
    FLAC_audioInputStream.close();
```

The resulting file can be analyzed (using `curl` or `recognizeUsingWebSocket()`) without any problems after adding an arbitrary number of frames. However, the `recognizeUsingWebSocket()` will return the final result as soon as it reaches the end of the FLAC file, even though the file's last frame may not be final (i.e., after `encodeSamples(count, false)`).

I would expect `recognizeUsingWebSocket()` to block till the final frame is written to the file. In practical terms, it means that the analysis stops after the first frame, as it takes less time to analyze the first frame than to collect the 2nd, so upon returning the results, the end of file is reached.

Is this the right way to implement streaming audio from a mic in Java? Seems like a common use case.

---

Here's a modification of `RecognizeUsingWebSocketsExample`, incorporating some of Daniel's suggestions below. It uses PCM content type (passed as a `String`, together with a frame size), and an attempt to signal the end of the audio stream, albeit not a very successful one.

As before, the connection is made, but the recognize callback is never called. Closing the stream does not seem to be interpreted as an end of audio either. I must be misunderstanding something here...

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, LineUnavailableException, InterruptedException {

    final PipedOutputStream output = new PipedOutputStream();
    final PipedInputStream  input  = new PipedInputStream(output);

  final AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(16000, 8, 1, true, false);
  DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);
  final TargetDataLine line = (TargetDataLine)AudioSystem.getLine(info);
  line.open(format);
  line.start();

    Thread thread1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
              final int MAX_FRAMES = 2;
              byte buffer[] = new byte[16000];
              for(int j1=0;j1<MAX_FRAMES;j1++) {  // read two frames from microphone
              int count = line.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
              System.out.println("Read audio frame from line: " + count);
              output.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
              System.out.println("Written audio frame to pipe: " + count);
              }
              /** no need to fake end-of-audio;  StopMessage will be sent 
              * automatically by SDK once the pipe is drained (see WebSocketManager)
              // signal end of audio; based on WebSocketUploader.stop() source
              byte[] stopData = new byte[0];
              output.write(stopData);
              **/
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    });
    thread1.start();

  final CountDownLatch lock = new CountDownLatch(1);

  SpeechToText service = new SpeechToText();
  service.setUsernameAndPassword("<username>", "<password>");

  RecognizeOptions options = new RecognizeOptions.Builder()
  .continuous(true)
  .interimResults(false)
  .contentType("audio/pcm; rate=16000")
  .build();

  service.recognizeUsingWebSocket(input, options, new BaseRecognizeCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onConnected() {
      System.out.println("Connected.");
    }
    @Override
    public void onTranscription(SpeechResults speechResults) {
    System.out.println("Received results.");
      System.out.println(speechResults);
      if (speechResults.isFinal())
        lock.countDown();
    }
  });

  System.out.println("Waiting for STT callback ... ");

  lock.await(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

  line.stop();

  System.out.println("Done waiting for STT callback.");

}
```

---

Dani, I instrumented the source for `WebSocketManager` (comes with SDK) and replaced a call to `sendMessage()` with an explicit `StopMessage` payload as follows:

```
        /**
     * Send input steam.
     *
     * @param inputStream the input stream
     * @throws IOException Signals that an I/O exception has occurred.
     */
    private void sendInputSteam(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
      int cumulative = 0;
      byte[] buffer = new byte[FOUR_KB];
      int read;
      while ((read = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        cumulative += read;
        if (read == FOUR_KB) {
          socket.sendMessage(RequestBody.create(WebSocket.BINARY, buffer));
        } else {
          System.out.println("completed sending " + cumulative/16000 + " frames over socket");
          socket.sendMessage(RequestBody.create(WebSocket.BINARY, Arrays.copyOfRange(buffer, 0, read)));  // partial buffer write
          System.out.println("signaling end of audio");
          socket.sendMessage(RequestBody.create(WebSocket.TEXT, buildStopMessage().toString()));  // end of audio signal

        }

      }
      inputStream.close();
    }
```

Neither of sendMessage() options (sending 0-length binary content or sending the stop text message) seems to work. The caller code is unchanged from above. The resulting output is:

```
Waiting for STT callback ... 
Connected.
Read audio frame from line: 16000
Written audio frame to pipe: 16000
Read audio frame from line: 16000
Written audio frame to pipe: 16000
completed sending 2 frames over socket
onFailure: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
```

REVISED: actually, the end-of-audio call is never reached. Exception is thrown while writing the last (partial) buffer to the socket.

Why is the connection aborted? That typically happens when the peer closes the connection.

As for point 2): Would either of these matter at this stage? It appears that recognition process is not being started at all... Audio is valid (I wrote the stream out to a disk and was able to recognize it by streaming it from a file, as I point out above).

Also, on further review of `WebSocketManager` source code, `onMessage()` already sends `StopMessage` immediately upon `return` from `sendInputSteam()` (ie.e., when the audio stream, or pipe in the example above, drains), so no need to call it explicitly. The problem is definitely occurring before the audio data transmission completes. The behavior is the same, regardless if `PipedInputStream` or `AudioInputStream` is passed as input. Exception is thrown while sending binary data in both cases.

Comment: q) have you been successful with wav files? establishing that you can then move to mic  2) HttpMediaType.AUDIO_WAV looks suspicious there

Comment: 1) yes, streaming a .wav file works just fine.  2) Good eye, but no cigar.  I already tried all 4 AUDIO formats supported by HttpMediaType (FLAC, OGG, RAW, WAV), but they all act the same way--connection is established but no transcripts are ever returned.

Comment: You can't use WAVE because you don't know the size in advance if you are streaming audio. 

You need to get the byte array from the Microphone (usually WAVE) and transform it into FLAC and then send it to the `RecognizeOptions`.

Comment: German, thanks, that helps.  I was able to create a FLAC audio file and append to it, frame-by-frame, with audio arriving from the mic.  The resulting file can be analyzed as whole (e.g., with curl or recognizeUsingWebSocket()).  However, I am not able to stream from the mic--the routine returns final result as soon as it reaches the end of file, even though the final frame was not written to it yet (I would expect it should block if the last frame is not final).  I'll update the question with details.

Comment: Seems like a better alternative for speech recognition of continuous streaming audio from a mic, particularly for short statements, would be to send data as multi-part using a session-based (stateful) POST.  Audio frames coming from the mic could be written out as individual files (e.g., one frame per file) and submitted separately.  I've seen some references to a Python implementation and some (not working) cURL examples.  is there anything out there in Java?

Answer (score 6):

The Java SDK has an example and supports this.

Update your `pom.xml` with:

```
 <dependency>
   <groupId>com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>java-sdk</artifactId>
   <version>3.3.1</version>
 </dependency>
```

Here is an example of how to listen to your microphone.

```
SpeechToText service = new SpeechToText();
service.setUsernameAndPassword("<username>", "<password>");

// Signed PCM AudioFormat with 16kHz, 16 bit sample size, mono
int sampleRate = 16000;
AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(sampleRate, 16, 1, true, false);
DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);

if (!AudioSystem.isLineSupported(info)) {
  System.out.println("Line not supported");
  System.exit(0);
}

TargetDataLine line = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
line.open(format);
line.start();

AudioInputStream audio = new AudioInputStream(line);

RecognizeOptions options = new RecognizeOptions.Builder()
  .continuous(true)
  .interimResults(true)
  .timestamps(true)
  .wordConfidence(true)
  //.inactivityTimeout(5) // use this to stop listening when the speaker pauses, i.e. for 5s
  .contentType(HttpMediaType.AUDIO_RAW + "; rate=" + sampleRate)
  .build();

service.recognizeUsingWebSocket(audio, options, new BaseRecognizeCallback() {
  @Override
  public void onTranscription(SpeechResults speechResults) {
    System.out.println(speechResults);
  }
});

System.out.println("Listening to your voice for the next 30s...");
Thread.sleep(30 * 1000);

// closing the WebSockets underlying InputStream will close the WebSocket itself.
line.stop();
line.close();

System.out.println("Fin.");
```

Comment: @RobertGrzeszczuk: If this answer helped you, please accept it. It is a help to others quickly find correct answer without reading each every information.

Comment: this example generates a first "final transcription" but after that, it just continues to generate "interim transcriptions" and never set the final flag true again. How can I process more than 1 transcription using a continuous websocket stream?

Comment: Each sentence will have a final=true

Comment: On version ```5.1.1``` it doesn't compile due to missing methods and errors . Any ideas :)

Comment: I will update this answer later @GOXR3PLUS, Try to use the examples in the repository https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk/blob/develop/examples/src/main/java/com/ibm/watson/developer_cloud/speech_to_text/v1/RecognizeUsingWebSocketsExample.java

Comment: Thanks I have pushed an issue on Github IBM Watson Java SDK Repository  with a solution for the newest version :)

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do is feed the audio to the STT service not as a file, but as a headerless stream of audio samples. You just feed the samples that you capture from the microphone over a WebSocket. You need to set the content type to "audio/pcm; rate=16000" where 16000 is the sampling rate in Hz. If your sampling rate is different, which depends on how the microphone is encoding the audio, you will replace the 16000 by your value, for example: 44100, 48000, etc.

When feeding pcm audio the STT service wont stop recognizing until you signal the end of audio by sending an empty binary message over the websocket.

Dani

---

Looking at the new version of your code I see some issues:

1) signaling end of audio can be done by sending an empty binary message through the websocket, that is not what you are doing. The lines

```
 // signal end of audio; based on WebSocketUploader.stop() source
 byte[] stopData = new byte[0];
 output.write(stopData);
```

are not doing anything since they wont result in an empty websocket message being sent. Can you please call the method "WebSocketUploader.stop()" instead?

2. You are capturing audio at 8 bits per sample, you should do 16 bits for enough queality. Also you are only feeding a couple of seconds of audio, not ideal for testing. Can you please write whatever audio you push to STT to a file and then open it with Audacity (using the import feature)? This way you can make sure what you are feeding to STT is good audio.

Comment: Thanks for helping out.  Do you mean: replace `.contentType(HttpMediaType.AUDIO_WAV)` with `.contentType("audio/pcm; rate=16000")` in the first example above?  Seems like a valid content type, but I get the same behavior as before: the connection just hangs there, and no results are returned.  I did confirm that `audio` is a valid stream (I can capture it in a file, a frame at a time, and pass to STT service without any problems).  Sampling rate is 16000 Hz, 8 bits, single channel.  Could you post a sample (or even add it to the distribution)?  Seems like a very common use case ...

Comment: you need to send an empty binary message signaling the end of audio once you are done sending all the chunks, please take a look at this example in python or ruby

https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-to-text-websockets-python
https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-to-text-websockets-ruby

Dani

Comment: Dani, perhaps I am misunderstanding you.  I'm using the 'SpeechToText' service--a wrapper around WebSockets that is included with the distribution examples. Since the 'client' member is private to the class, I cannot write anything directly to the socket, and writing an empty buffer to the input stream does not seem to effect the outcome (as expected). Are you saying that instead of relying on 'SpeechToText' service, I should build it from scratch using WebSockets along the lines of Python example you pointed to?  If so, are there any code samples in Java? Thanks again for helping out.

Comment: On a separate note, WebSocketManager (which implements the STT service) seems to be sending a text STOP message, not a zero-length binary message, and is constructed within buildStopMessage(), which is, unfortunately, private.

Comment: Hi Robert, sending the stop message is also valid, it is equivalent to sending the empty binary message, so you can use that.

Comment: Dani, I posted a code sample above: passing PCM contentType and attempting to signal the end of audio.  Still, no luck.  I must be misunderstanding your suggestions.

Comment: Dani, I instrumented the code and traced the problem to a partial buffer write to the socket (see above for code sample).  Any idea why the connection is being aborted?

Comment: Hi Robert, try to do one basic thing so you can build confidence in what you are doing: a) push all your audio at once, just one binary message, no chunking, b) signal the end of audio with an empty binary message (btw. what you are doing is not corect: "socket.sendMessage(RequestBody.create(WebSocket.TEXT, buildStopMessage().toString()));  // end of audio signal", this is a TEXT message, it must be BINARY)

Comment: Dani, as I pointed out very clearly above, the code you are referring to is the IBM SDK, not ours.  
I only instrumented it for you so that it is apparent where the problem resides.
StopMessage *is* TEXT not BINARY, the audio stream *is* chunked, and the end-of-audio signal *is* sent automatically 
once the input stream is drained.  Perhaps you can convince yourself
of that by reviewing the SDK implementation?

Comment: At this point, I think we reached our limits here.  
Is there someone on the STT team who is familiar with this code 
and who can move this process forward?

Comment: Hi Robert, please contact us through the IBM support channel... we will solve your issue there. thank you.