# Speech-to-text from a LIVE stream

Tags: live, speech-to-text, wowza

I have a Java application and I want to transcribe, not a file, but a LIVE stream(rtmp:// or m3u8) that is being served by Wowza.

Is that possible?

Thank you

PS: I'm willing to pay any of those cloud services that offer audio transcription, but the ones I've seen don't seem to have this functionality.

Comment: Hi RichardW, Watson STT does not support this out of the box, but this could be accomplished on your end by implementing a bridge rtmp <> websockets. What volume of speech do you plan to push to the STT service?

Answer (score 5):

There are a few options!

Google has one that is in beta, but seems very promising! Their documentation is a little light at this point but here is a good github example. https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/speech

and their documention on it:

https://cloud.google.com/java/

The other option is IBM's Bluemix:
https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/text-to-speech-java

Best of luck! If you end up trying out both I would love to have an update on which one you felt worked best!

**EDIT** Another useful link: [Stream audio from mic to IBM Watson SpeechToText Web service using Java SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37232560/stream-audio-from-mic-to-ibm-watson-speechtotext-web-service-using-java-sdk)  while it doesn't interface with Wowza, this might be a good place to start for IBM.